# Extracting group by data for each group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Excel sheet

participantData.xlsx

```
email      Name     Date        RegPushupCount    EasyPushupCount    DifficultPushupCount
a@b.com    John     2020-05-01         5                  0                   0
a@b.com    John     2020-05-01         5                  0                   0
a@b.com    John     2020-05-02         0                  5                   0
a@b.com    Jane     2020-05-02         5                  0                   0
a@b.com    Jane     2020-05-01         0                  0                   5
b@a.com    Bill     2020-05-01         0                  0                   5
b@a.com    Bill     2020-05-02         0                  5                   0
```

I want to send an email to every email, a summary of how many pushups they have done. I got a function send_email( email_address, email_text) this will take  care of the email part.

I want to send email like this

**email to: a@b.com**

```
John               Regular Push ups     Easy Push ups   Difficult Pushups
      2020-05-01          10               0                    0
      2020-05-02          0                5                    0
Jane               Regular Push ups     Easy Push ups   Difficult Pushups
      2020-05-01          5                0                    0
      2020-05-02          0                5                    0
```

---

**email to: b@a.com**

```
Bill               Regular Push ups     Easy Push ups   Difficult Pushups
      2020-05-01          10               0                    0
      2020-05-02          0                5                    0
```

I hope this explains clearly.

Here is how far I have come:

```
participantsData = pd.DataFrame(
...       pushupCountXLS.groupby(['Email', 'Name', 'Date'] ).sum().astype(int))
```

Please can you guide me how I can extract the data for each email address from the dataframe and send them email about the push ups they have done.

Just in case if you are wondering, a group of us friends are running a 100 days pushups challenge, we enter this data in google sheet and this is like a confirmation email to them from the google sheet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem, if you have any ideas for optimizing this please do not hesitate to comment. Thank you! Thanks to @Mayank Porwal for your help

```
participantsData = pushupCountXLS.groupby(['Email', 'Name', 'Date'], as_index=False ).agg(sum)
uniqueEmailAdd = participantsXLS['Email Address'].unique()
for em in uniqueEmailAdd:
    if check_valid_email(str(em)):
        temp = participantsData[participantsData['Email'].eq(em)]
        temp = temp.astype({'Regular':int, 'Easy':int, 'Special':int})
        uniqunames=(temp['Name'].unique())
        strtemp2=""
        for participant in uniqunames:
            #strtemp2 = temp[['Date', 'Regular', 'Easy', 'Special']].to_string(index=False)
            temp2 = temp[temp['Name'].eq(participant)]
            strtemp2 = str(participant) + '\n'
            strtemp2 += temp2[['Date', 'Regular', 'Easy', 'Special']].to_string(index=False)
        emailcounter += 1
        print(emailcounter)
        send_email(em, strtemp2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
In [1476]: df.groupby(['email','Name','Date']).agg('sum')
Out[1476]: 
                         RegPushupCount  EasyPushupCount  DifficultPushupCount
email   Name Date                                                             
a@b.com Jane 2020-05-01               0                0                     5
             2020-05-02               5                0                     0
        John 2020-05-01              10                0                     0
             2020-05-02               0                5                     0
b@a.com Bill 2020-05-01               0                0                     5
             2020-05-02               0                5                     0
```

#### After OP's comment:

```
In [1566]: res = df.groupby(['email','Name','Date'], as_index=False).agg('sum')
```

You can get all records for `a@b.com` like this:

```
In [1568]: res[res['email'].eq('a@b.com')]
Out[1568]: 
     email  Name        Date  RegPushupCount  EasyPushupCount  DifficultPushupCount
0  a@b.com  Jane  2020-05-01               0                0                     5
1  a@b.com  Jane  2020-05-02               5                0                     0
2  a@b.com  John  2020-05-01              10                0                     0
3  a@b.com  John  2020-05-02               0                5                     0
```

You can get all records for b@a.com like this:

```
In [1569]: res[res['email'].eq('b@a.com')]
Out[1569]: 
     email  Name        Date  RegPushupCount  EasyPushupCount  DifficultPushupCount
4  b@a.com  Bill  2020-05-01               0                0                     5
5  b@a.com  Bill  2020-05-02               0                5                     0
```

Comment: I want to get the records for the email address a@b.com and do something with it and then take the records for b#a.com and do the different thing with it. 

Am I making sense?

I want to access the set of records to manipulate (send email to)

Comment: @N2201 Please check the 2nd part of my update answer. I have updated it as per your requirements.

Comment: I added an answer to this problem on how I solved it with your help. would appreciate if you can take a look. Thank you!